# How do I save an output file from Django to Amazon S3

Tags: python, django, heroku, amazon-s3

As part of the process, my site crates a csv file from a pandas dataframe -

> df.to_csv()

As the application is deployed on Heroku, here there is no persistent file storage, I want to save this to Amazon S3.  I have this set up for uploaded files and static files, but can't get it to work for this.  Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use [django-storages](http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) to save your files to Amazon S3. Add your AWS credentials to your config like this:

```
heroku config:add AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='your_key_here'
heroku config:add AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='your_secret_here'
heroku config:add AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME='your_bucket_name_here'
```

and retrieve them in your *settings.py* like this:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
```

Update: You can try `StringIO` to do something like this:

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from StringIO import StringIO

output = StringIO()
df.to_csv(output)
mymodel.myfield.save('django_test.csv', ContentFile(output.getvalue()))
```

Comment: I'm using django-storages for static and uploaded media files, that's working fine.  How do I use it to save a file that is created in the course of the program running?  df.to_csv(s3_storage.open(...)) does not work...

Comment: I think you need something like `with open(csv_filename, 'rb') as f:mymodel.myfield.save('django_test.csv', File(f), save=True) `

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Boto. The code is really easy and your don't have to worry about writing the file out just post it directly.

```
heroku config:add AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='your_key_here'
heroku config:add AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='your_secret_here'
```

Boto will use the config automatically:

```
import boto
filecontents = "colm1, colm2, etc"
c = boto.connect_s3()
b = c.get_bucket('mybucket') # substitute your bucket name here
from boto.s3.key import Key
k = Key(b)
k.key = filecontents
k.get_contents_as_string()
'colm1, colm2, etc'
```

Read more: http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/s3_tut.html